# How to Change Position of a control depending on selected value of ComboEdit at runtime in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, devexpress, dynamic-controls

[image]I have a ComboEdit which shows Country List in it. On the form their is an ADDRESS tab which is set to active on selection of ComboEdit value. The Position of Controls on ADDRESS tab must be change according to Layout Specified (can we use here Databsase to store the layout depending on Country selected) .

I want to display Address format & the controls dyanamically as per order specifed as per company choosen from comboedit. Please see for Different Address formats : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195167.aspx.

I want to change the change position of control according to country selected. Any suggestion/idea?
**Currently i am using two different Grid and making Visible/Hide depending on Country Value. This is ok for one or two countries but not possible to add that much Grid so want to store it in to Database. Please suggest me right method...!**

```
<Grid Name="grdGroupA" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0,0,95,21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="714">
                        <Label Content="Honorific"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAHonorific" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtAHonorific_LostFocus"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAFirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" LostFocus="txtAFirstName_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="First Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAMiddleName" Margin="0,31,185,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64" LostFocus="txtAMiddleName_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="Middle Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtALastName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,31,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" LostFocus="txtALastName_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="Last Name" Margin="0,27,99,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="66" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.045,0.577"/>
                        <Label Content="Company Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtACompanyName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="Address1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAAddress1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtAAddress1_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="Address2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAAddress2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtAAddress2_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="City"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtACity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtACity_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="State"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtAState_LostFocus"/>
                        <Label Content="Postal Code"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="410,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtAPostalCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="487,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95" LostFocus="txtAPostalCode_LostFocus"/>
                        <Button Content="Save" Visibility="Hidden" Name="BtnASave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="330,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnASave_Click"/>
                        <Button Content="Cancel" Name="BtnACancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="492,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnACancel_Click"/>
                        <Button Content="Update" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="BtnAEdit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="410,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnAEdit_Click_1"/>
                        <Button Content="Add New" x:Name="BtnAAddNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="250,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnAAddNew_Click"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAHonorificError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <!--<Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAHonorificError_Copy" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>-->
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAAddress1Error" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAAddress2Error" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblACityError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAStateError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="384,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAPostalCodeError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="581,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAFirstNameError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="370,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblAMiddleNameError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="529,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <Label Content="*" x:Name="lblALastNameError" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="677,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                    </Grid>
<Grid Name="grdGroupB" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,141,21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="668">
                        <Label Content="Honorific"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBHonorific" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBFirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64"/>
                        <Label Content="First Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBMiddleName" Margin="0,27,144,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64"/>
                        <Label Content="Middle Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBLastName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,27,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64"/>
                        <Label Content="Last Name" Margin="0,27,73,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="66"/>
                        <Label Content="Company Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBCompanyName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="Address1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBAddress1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="Address2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBAddress2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="City"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBCity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="95"/>
                        <Label Content="State"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="64"/>
                        <Label Content="Postal Code"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtBPostalCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="460,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1,0.091" Width="64"/>
                        <Button Content="Save" Name="BtnBSave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="412,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                        <Button Content="Cancel" Name="BtnBCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="492,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

                    </Grid>
```

As all the controls in Grid. how to set position depending country selected?

Help Appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Please use [Grid's Rows and Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) and don't use the hard-coded `Margin` for layout purposes.

Comment: yes you are right! As i am new to WPF so just drag n drop on form. But, i will go for it..later on..! :)

Comment: If you use Grid.Row and Grid.Column then you can set bindings for that. With that you can alter the position of any element inside the Grid to suit your needs.

Comment: Anyway i don't see the reason why would you want to move your controls in the two screenshots above. And in your Address Formats link the formats indicates the string you would normally write in a letter or document so you don't have to move them around in an Edit/View Form. All you have to do is to change the visibility of the TextBoxes based on selected Country and in this case the Grid and StackPanel is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if it's too late to suggest you the following but I would prefer an approach with different VMs (one for each possible country) reflecting the address data. Then you could create for each selectable country a `DataTemplate` (one for each address vm). The next you would need is a `TemplateSelector` which selects the right `DataTemplate` according to the VM passed to it.

That means, if the address VM is changed according to the selected country in the `ComboBox`, the `TemplateSelector` would choose the related `DataTemplate`. With this approach you could easily extend your application for additional countries, if necessary.

Please note, that this solution respects the MVVM pattern (not sure if you're using it) and that the text above is just a description of my idea how such a requirement could be implemented. You might have to solve some issues before being successful.

For more information please follow the links

- [`DataTemplates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)
- [`TemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)
- [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: Sorry @DHN! As I am new to WPF so cant go for this solution but your interest for help appreciated...! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that changes the display order of two labels

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.JsonWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="JsonWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Label 1" Grid.Row="{Binding label1}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Label 2" Grid.Row="{Binding label2}"/>
        <Button Content="Change Position" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class JsonWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public JsonWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        label1 = 0;
        label2 = 1;
    }

    public int label1 {get;set;}

    public int label2 { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        label1 = 1;
        label2 = 0;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("label1"));
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("label2"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

But as **@Novitchi S** said, you will have to do away with your margins technique. Use Grid.Row and Grid.Column.